# python 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed

Tags: python, 22.04, cuda

I'm trying to run this line in my ubuntu 22.04 terminal to setup CUDA:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-tk python-imaging-tk
```

but get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-pil.imagetk' instead of 'python-imaging-tk'
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04).
python3-dev set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2-stdlib : Breaks: libpython-stdlib (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
 python2 : Breaks: python (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
 python2-minimal : Breaks: python-minimal (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
 python3-six : Breaks: libpython-stdlib (< 2.7.18) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
               Breaks: python-minimal (< 2.7.18) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
 python3-yaml : Breaks: libpython-stdlib (< 2.7.18) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
                Breaks: python-minimal (< 2.7.18) but 2.7.15~rc1-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've searched and tried a lot of things but nothing works. Every time I check:

```
apt-cache policy python libpython2.7-minimal
```

the output is still:

```
python:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.15~rc1-1
  Version table:
     2.7.15~rc1-1 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libpython2.7-minimal:
  Installed: 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.18-13ubuntu1 500
        500 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
     2.7.15~rc1-1 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Does someone has any idea?

Comment: Why do you have `bionic` sources in 22.04?

Comment: is that a problem? i'm quite new and didn't really know why that happens and what should  I do now

Comment: Yes, that is a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: The package `python-imaging-tk` does not exist in your version of Ubuntu. You might be following some outdated tutorials. Please ask a new question about what you are trying to do, and which all steps you followed.